# How to open activity/app when fcm onMessageReceived receive a data message even if the app is killed - Android Studio

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, incoming-call

I've a calling app in which I'm working with real time calling with `fcm`. I'm able to send and receive call when app is live and in background by taking permission for battery optimisation. Problem is when the app is killed or remove from recent app list I am getting `onReceivedMessage` of `fcm` called but how should I start my activity to show incoming call to the second user. Please help me on this.

Below is my `onMessageReceived` code:

```
 public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);

        String type = message.getData().get(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_TYPE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+message.getData());
        if (type != null) {
            if (type.equals(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingInvitation.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MESSAGE_MEETING_TYPE, message.getData().get(Constants.REMOTE_MESSAGE_MEETING_TYPE));
                intent.putExtra(Constants.name, message.getData().get(Constants.name));
                intent.putExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MESSAGE_INVITER_TOKEN, message.getData().get(Constants.REMOTE_MESSAGE_INVITER_TOKEN));
                intent.putExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_MEETING_ROOM, message.getData().get(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_MEETING_ROOM));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (type.equals(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE, message.getData().get(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE));
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

As discussed above I'm getting calls when app is alive or in background but not when app is killed or remove from memory. I want to start app when a call received when the app is not in the memory.